# PDO Prepared Statement Function

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO prepared statements, while working on my current project i decided to just create several function for each action that i would need. Below is the example for fetch

```
function db_fetchAll($sql, $param) {
    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    if (empty($param)) {
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        $stmt->execute($param);
    }

    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($count == 0) {
        $result = "";
    } elseif ($count == 1) {
        $result[] = $stmt->fetch();
    } elseif ($count > 1) {
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Example

```
$database = db_fetchAll("SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE id=:id", array(':id' => $id));
```

It only condenses lines query's from 3 lines to 1, but with the amount of information required for each page it was worth condensing.

I am going back through the project for one final pass through and i just wanted a second opinion on the security of this. If there is anything that i should add, etc. All user_input is passed through this function

```
function user_input($input) {
    $input = trim($input);  
    $output = strip_tags($input);

    return $output;
}
```

and all output uses htmlspecialchars.

So the question in a nutshell is:
Is this safe?
Is there anything else that i could do to prevent any other form of injection etc?

I completely understand how prepared statements work, i am just being thorough, version 1 of this site was a nightmare, tons of injections, gaining access to admin accounts, etc.

Comment: What are you asking?  Are you asking if it's safe?  You're using prepared statements, and you are using them correctly... it's fine.

Comment: Yes that was the question, i made the edit to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: You might want to check the return value of `$stmt->execute();` for errors.

Comment: You are right Mr. Common Sense, e.g. he might want PDO to throw Exceptions.

Comment: During production mode ( defined in global file ) Errors are not thrown ( error_reporting(0) ) They are just logged. Also for pages that are dependent on a specific query ( example user profile ) if the function returns empty the page is redirected to 404. On other pages where it just displays information, if function returns empty the information just stays hidden.

Comment: What is the particular setting you are talking about?

Comment: I am talking about setting error_reporting(0) so errors do not appear on user side if one occurs.

Comment: this is the worst disservce you can do yourself ever. it have to be E_ALL unconditionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 for such an intention. A quite embarrassing number, but only one out of thousand users asking questions regarding PDO here ever think of such a natural thing like a helper function.

Just a few notes.

- First of all, there is an essential flaw with your code which is trying to detect the result type automatically. I tried it myself and I can assure you it's just a source of disaster. The less magic in your code the more hair you keep on your head. So, instead of such unreliable magic, just make different functions to return different result sets.
- Second, you have to make default value for the parameters? to be able to run query without placeholders.
- Third, some code is just superfluous. There is no need to check $param variable.

Finally, your function should be looking like

```
function db_fetchAll($sql, $param = array()) {
    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($param);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

and **always return the array of rows as the name suggests**

As of the other functions with different result sets, it seems that PDO, if very slightly tweaked, can offer exactly the same convenience without any helper function at all. You may take a look at the [PDO wrapper I made to ease the pain of transition from old mysql ext](https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper)

Your code will remain almost the same

```
$data = DB::query("SELECT * FROM database_table")->fetchAll();
```

yet it will let you to use all the poser of PDO different resultset methods:

```
$row = DB::prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?")->execute([$id])->fetch();
```

or even

```
$sql  = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?";
$name = DB::prepare($sql)->execute([$id])->fetchColumn();
```

and so on

Comment: So switching over to the second suggestion is more of a preference to avoid using helpers correct? The entire site is complete and if it is a preference and does not offer any added benefits then i will end up sticking with the helpers. 

I removed the count i do not know why i used that in each helper. 

I do not want errors appearing on user end so i will be looking into turning off error reporting but retaining logs, ( i thought i had that already setup but i apparently do not ) 

Thank you for the help.

Comment: it seems you didn't get the main point. well, you will learn it from the experience.